# Best way to delay shared_ptr<> from being destructed in C++

Tags: c++, destructor, shared-ptr

I have an application which have used raw pointers and `std::shared_ptr`. Because of the intermixes, `shared_ptr` deletes the objects too early.

What is the best way to delay this? Sure, just making it all raw is the easiest. What's the best practice?

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46797586/edit) the relevant code (chunk).

Comment: `shared_ptr` deletes the object when the last `shared_ptr` that points to the object goes out of scope. If the object is being deleted too soon, it's because the last `shared_ptr` is going away too soon.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The problem is not that `std::shared_ptr` deletes objects too early, but that your design pattern or whatever you use is not keeping them alive for as long as you need them.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to mix `shared_ptr`s with raw pointers. There are only a few situations/patterns where you can (relatively) safely do it.

Comment: *What is the best way to delay this?* Change the raw pointers that still need the pointer to shared or weak pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver `weak_ptr` won't keep any objects alive but it'll help with diagnosing where the problem actually is.

Comment: @navyblue Correct.  I only added it as a suggestion as it expression the type of relationship it has.

Comment: 'What is the best way to delay this?' - use shared_ptr properly.

Comment: easy: store another copy of your ptr in a shared_ptr you add to some  global vector, and wait the exit of program. No, I'm kidding. use shared_ptr in the way they are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

> `shared_ptr` deletes the objects too early. What is the best way to delay this? What's the best practice?

Best practice is to make a copy of the shared pointer. Keep that copy around for as long as you need the object to stay alive.